# How to find the risk neutral valuation of $P(T_{1})$ und the measure $\mathbb Q^{P(T_{2})}$

Tags: options, option-pricing, interest-rates, risk-neutral-measure, martingale

How do I find the risk neutral valuation of $P(T_{1})$ und the measure $\mathbb Q^{P(T_{2})}$, where $P(T_{1})$ and $P(T_{2})$ refer to the $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ zero coupon bond with $0 < T_{1} < T_{2}$, and $L(T_{1},T_{2},t)$ be the associated forward rate. The forward rate is assumed to be follow lognormal law under $\mathbb Q  ^{P(T_{2})}$.  I first note that $P(T_{1},t)=P(T_{2},t)(1+L(T_{1},T_{2};t)(T_{2}-T_{1}))$ such that it can be seen as a function of two traded instruments in the $T_{2}$ market, i.e. $P(T_{1},t)=f(P(T_{2},t),L(T_{1},T_{2};t))$. Therefore, I think(?) that $(\frac{P(T_{1},t)}{P(T_{2},t)})_{0\leq t \leq T_{1}}$ is a $\mathbb Q ^{P(T_{2})}$ martingale. Such that the risk-neutral valuation looks like

$$V(0)\stackrel{?}{=}P(T_{2},0)\mathbb E ^{\mathbb Q^{P(T_{2})}}\left[\frac{P(T_{1},T_{1})}{P(T_{2},T_{1})}\right]= P(T_{2},0)\mathbb E ^{\mathbb Q^{P(T_{2})}}\left[\frac{1}{P(T_{2},T_{1})}\right]=P(T_{2},0)\mathbb E ^{\mathbb Q^{P(T_{2})}}\left[1+L(T_{1},T_{2};T_{1})(T_{2}-T_{1})\right]=P(T_{2},0)(1+L(T_{1},T_{2};0)(T_{2}-T_{1}))$$

Am I not sure on the first equality (where I put the question mark) as I have only used the fact that $\frac{P(T_{1},t)}{P(T_{2},t)}$ is a martingale up to time $T_{1}$ but not necessarily up to $T_{2}$.

I think I may be making this harder than it is, but I just want to have sound reasoning as to why I can/cannot do the above. Thanks!